# How to declare methods in a ClassX factory so that its sub-factories can use sub-classes ClassX-1 constants?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

I have a MapFactory, which is an abstract class that implements the shared methods among the sub-factory classes Map1Creator, Map2Creator, Map3Creator, ..., MapNCreator
These nCreators return a Map1(which extends a Map class) which has been initialized with the constants in the classes MapN.
My professor asked to use a factory pattern instead of constructors, so I had to remove them among my MapN classes.

The Map class:

```
public abstract class Map {

    protected Sector[][] grid;
    protected List<Integer> dangerousSectCoord ;
    protected List<Integer> normalSectCoord;
    //[...]
    protected List<Integer> emptySectCoord;
    //all the getters...
}
```

While in the subclass Map1 (the strings because they'll be read from file):

```
public class Map1 extends Map{
    private final static int ROWS_NUMBER=14;
    private final static int COLS_NUMBER=23;
    private final static String normSectorString= "all the sectors...";
    private final static String dangerousSectorString [......]
    private final static String escapeSectorString="B10,F01,P01,V11";

}
```

In the MapFactory I can't specify methods with only one kind of MapN, so I can only write non-specific methods:

```
public abstract class MapFactory {
    public abstract Map createMap();
    //here there should be 
    //assignSectors(Map m);
    //setDimensions(Map m);
    //but MapN can't be converted to Map and in the MapNCreator Eclipse
    //reminds me that I must implement the father's methods

    public List<Integer> mapStrings(String string){
        List<Integer> coor=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //parse sub-classes strings and convert them to coordinates;
    }
}
```

So in the MapNCreator:

```
public class Map1Creator extends MapFactory{
    public Map1 createMap(){
        Map1 m= new MapGalvani();
        setDimensions(m)
         assignSectors(m);
        return null;
     }

    public void setDimensions(Map1 m ) {
        m.grid= new Sector[m.getRowsNumber()][m.getColsNumber()];
        m.alienSectCoord=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //[...]
        m.emptySectCoord=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public void assignSectors(Map1 m){
        //parse those constant strings and put them in the grid
        //m.constantStringNormalSectors 
    }
```

But as you can see the "m" map is specifically a Map1 and the methods need the constants inside the Map1 class. If I declare those methods in the MapFactory it gives me an error in the MapNCreators, as they cannot convert from Map to MapN (I thought polymorphism would cover this...).
Is there a way to declare methods in a "father" factory class so that any sub-creator class will be able to use them with their own type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, a year later: inside the father class make a generic return/parameter type:

```
<T extends Map> or <? extends Map>
```